# Not able to install the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on Windows 8.1 OS

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013 Express for Windows on my Windows 2008.1 PC.
I am trying to install the visual studio 2015 community edition on the same P.C.  but it is giving the error as shown in figure below.

[image]

So I downloaded the update of KB2919355. But when I tried to install the update it gives following error.

[image]

After this I have also applied some updates provided by the official site of M.Soft.
Following updates were applied by me.

[image]

Then again I tried to install the update KB2919355 and got the same error again.

Please suggest me the correct way to install the VS 2015 on my Windows 8.1 P.C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same issue and after digging it I found that the installation of KB2919355 update requires the installation of [KB2919442](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42162) (check your system if it is 32 bit or 64 bit).

After these installation restart the computer and then install the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.